# Best way to store material properties in Python material calculator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, global-variables

I'm about to program a calculator for engineers that allows to calculate some structure's properties based on what material it is built of.

I have a bunch of materials and each of them has the same set properties (strength, density etc.)

The user will input some structure-specific properties (size, position etc.) and based on that and the materials properties, the calculator will output the structure's properties (eg. various stresses, pressures etc.)

What is the best way to store the material properties? For now I think I will use a module with a bunch of classes in it:

```
class Concrete_1:
      strength=1
      hardness=1.5
class Concrete_2:
      strength=3
      hardness=7
```

that way In all the calculations I can use simple way of referring to each material property, eg:

```
StructureProperty=properties.Concrete_1.strength*UserInput
```

Do you think it is a good way? I am not aiming for a masterpiece of code, but also I want to make sure that this is not a dumb idea. What are smart ways of dealing with such thing.

Comment: What about instances of your class? e.g. `concrete = Material(1, 1.5)`

Comment: @Justlearnedit  I am not sure if it is convenient to store and edit in the long run. Each type of concrete has plenty of properties, not just strength and hardness, so in the end it would look like this:
Concrete_1=Material(5,42,6,1,7,523,5..........)
Concrete_2=Material(4,21,6,33,7,242,6.......)
So it wouldn't be easy to read and maintain a tidy archive of materials.

Comment: Convinced :) classes also look better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without too much context, I would recommend you to go for a solution of this kind:

```
class Material:

    strength = None
    hardness = None

    @classmethod
    def calculate_strength_related_property(cls, user_input):
        return user_input * cls.strength

class Concrete1(Material):

    strength = 1
    hardness = 2

class Concrete2(Material):

    strength = 3
    hardness = 4
```

Define a super class that makes all the calculations you need with the user input (I just made a very simple example) and returns the information you need for your Structure Properties. Then, you can create your new Material sub classes and define their properties as you did before. By defining it as a class method, you avoid instancing materials that only hold constants.

A use example would be:

```
structure_property = Concrete1.calculate_strength_related_property(user_input)
```

The solution you proposed will definitely work and I would personally say is not *wrong*, but I believe this approach is a little bit fancier.

**NOTE:** Attribute definition in Material class is not necessary, but I think that if every sub class shares them it's nice to have them there.

Comment: Very neat! It can really make the rest of code simpler. Great suggestion!